# "Deleted" viewcontroller from MainWindow.xib. Is this possible?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xib, viewcontroller, mainwindow

So I accidentally removed the viewcontroller from the mainwindow.xib in xcode.  I tried dragging the xib back into the mainwindow, but nothing is working.  Is there anyway to get the viewcontroller back onto the mainwindow?  When I run the app all that is showing is the window, not the viewcontroller so I know I did something wrong.

Comment: Try with Cmd + Z (several times) in the MainWindow.xib

Comment: @Elvis I can't undo, did I mess this up?  I can always copy the xib from an older project.

Comment: Create another project - look at all the IB bindings for the view controller and apply them yourself to match.  You'll learn quite a bit about what's going on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do all kinds of things accidentally using Xcode, make sure to use the integrated git repository or make a manual backup of files from time to time.

As stated by bryanmac, you can create a new project and learn how interface builder binding works.

Here's a good tutorial for starters:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-interface-builder-basic-training/